# pyodbc error calling iSeries stored procedure

Tags: pyodbc

Getting this error message when calling a stored proc from python script to iSeries pgm, pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0443 
- Trigger program or external routine detected an error. (-443) (SQLExecDirectW)')

My dsn is set up as

```py
    with pyodbc.connect(dsn=dsn_name, autocommit=True) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            log.info("Calling proc IPP201CSP (CL IPP201C) with no parameters")
            cursor.execute("{CALL IPP201CSP}")
'''

Already saw this which seems to say add autocommit=True which is what I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927687/error-when-calling-a-procedure-from-pyodbc
```